# Cite chapter without number in IEEE

Tags: citations, ieee, bachelor

I'm writing a report where I need to use the following document as a reference: https://ibex-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_reference/index.html

I want to cite this reference as accurately as possible in-text. I've considered citing the chapters I have used, for example, [1, Ch. 3]. The only problem is that the source doesn't number the different chapters. Would it be ok to, for example, cite like this: [1, Ch. "chapter x"]? If not, how should I do this?

Comment: Do you mean the chapters are named but not numbered? You could consider citing the page (range) instead.

Comment: Yes exactly. That would be an option, except the documentation includes no page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to follow the suggestion in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/182711/17254), which is to look for a single PDF version of the documentation. A PDF is more likely to include chapter and page numbering than the online version of the documentation. In your case, a link to download such a PDF version can be found by clicking "Read the Docs", which leads to [here](https://ibex-core.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/). Unfortunately, it has some formatting issues and is missing some figures. If that's a deal breaker probably it is best to cite specific "chapters" as individual websites.